# example for print barcode cl-s621 Citizen

Tags: printing, vb6, barcode

I have a citizen cl-s621 printer, where can i find example for programming code39 or ean code  barcode label.
I've worked with zebra y sato printer, and never with citizen.

Answer (score 1):

According to specification, CL-S621 can emulate Zebra ZPL-II language.

https://www.citizen-systems.com/us/products/printer/label/cl-s621/

This is an example of barcode 39 printing to Zebra printer. Refactoring required.

```
' module code

Public Type DOCINFO
    pDocName As String
    pOutputFile As String
    pDatatype As String
End Type

Public Declare Function ClosePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EndDocPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EndPagePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function OpenPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "OpenPrinterA" (ByVal pPrinterName As String, phPrinter As Long, ByVal pDefault As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function StartDocPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "StartDocPrinterA" (ByVal hPrinter As Long, ByVal Level As Long, pDocInfo As DOCINFO) As Long
Public Declare Function StartPagePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function WritePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal hPrinter As Long, pBuf As Any, ByVal cdBuf As Long, pcWritten As Long) As Long

Public Const BARCODE_PLACEHOLDER = "@@@@@"
' label script created using ZebraDesigner
Public Const LABEL_TEMPLATE_39 = "^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTD^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR6,6~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ" _
                            & "^XA" _
                            & "^MMT" _
                            & "^PW609" _
                            & "^LL0406" _
                            & "^LS0" _
                            & "^BY4,3,160^FT586,219^B3I,N,,Y,N" _
                            & "^FD@@@@@^FS" _
                            & "^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ"

Public Function AddMOD43CheckChar(Text As String) As String
    Const charSet As String = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-. $/+%"
    Dim I As Long
    Dim T As Long
    For I = 1 To Len(Trim$(UCase(Text)))
        T = InStr(charSet, Mid$(Text, I, 1)) - 1 + T
    Next I
    
    AddMOD43CheckChar = Text & Mid$(charSet, (T Mod 43 + 1), 1)
End Function

Public Function ClearCommandChars(Text As String) As String
    Dim sTmp As String
    sTmp = Replace(Text, "^", vbNullString, Compare:=vbBinaryCompare)
    sTmp = Replace(sTmp, "~", vbNullString, Compare:=vbBinaryCompare)
    ClearCommandChars = Replace(sTmp, "_", vbNullString, Compare:=vbBinaryCompare)
End Function

Public Function PrintCode39toZebra(PrinterName As String, BarCodeText As String, Optional AddCheckChar As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim sBCtext         As String
    Dim lPrinterHandle  As Long, lRetVal As Long, lWritten As Long
    Dim tDocInfo        As DOCINFO
    
    ' clear barcode text and add check character
    sBCtext = ClearCommandChars(BarCodeText)
    If AddCheckChar Then sBCtext = AddMOD43CheckChar(sBCtext)
    
    ' insert barcode into label template
    sBCtext = Replace(LABEL_TEMPLATE_39, BARCODE_PLACEHOLDER, sBCtext, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
    
    ' send label script to printer
    tDocInfo.pDocName = "LoremIpsum"
    tDocInfo.pOutputFile = vbNullString
    tDocInfo.pDatatype = vbNullString

    lRetVal = OpenPrinter(PrinterName, lPrinterHandle, 0)
    If lRetVal <> 0 Then
        lRetVal = StartDocPrinter(lPrinterHandle, 1, tDocInfo)
        If lRetVal <> 0 Then
            lRetVal = StartPagePrinter(lPrinterHandle)
            If lRetVal <> 0 Then
                lRetVal = WritePrinter(lPrinterHandle, ByVal sBCtext, Len(sBCtext), lWritten)
                If lRetVal <> 0 Then
                    lRetVal = EndPagePrinter(lPrinterHandle)
                    If lRetVal <> 0 Then
                        lRetVal = EndDocPrinter(lPrinterHandle)
                        If lRetVal <> 0 Then
                            ClosePrinter lPrinterHandle
                            PrintCode39toZebra = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function

' form code

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    ' "ZDesigner GX420d" - printer name from Devices and Printers
    ' "01234" - test barcode text
    
    PrintCode39toZebra "ZDesigner GX420d", "01234", True
End Sub
```

[image: test barcode]

Comment: I checked the documentation is for net framework, but my application is for visual basic 6. Any example that can help me little bet?

Comment: Could you help me to with one example for emulating zebra for citizen?

Comment: What driver i have to use zebra driver or citizen driver?

Comment: Citizen driver. CL-S621 automatically recognizes ZPL scripts.